# Reading data from a network connection without making assumptions about bit representation

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, undefined-behavior, bit-representation

I want to transfer data from a client to a server. The data is stored in a `Data`:

```
class Data{
     Type1 Obj1;
     Type2 Obj2;
     Type3 Obj3;
     //...
}
```

First I insert the `data` into a buffer type:

```
Buffer(data);
```

Then I use one of Boost.Asio's send functions:

```
Send(endpoint_s, buffer_1)
```

Alternatively, I could send `Data` directly:

```
Send(endpoint_s, &data, sizeof(Data));
```

On the receiving end, I am expecting a `Data`. First I receive the data into a Buffer.

```
Receive(endpoint_c, buffer_2);
```

Now `buffer_2` contains a collection of bits that represents a `Data` **on the server's machine**. I wish I could just `reinterpret_cast` these bits into a `Data`, however, this results in undefined behavior. How am I supposed to convert the collection of bits in `buffer_2` into a `Data` in a way that does not result in undefined behavior?

Comment: Search for "serialization" and you'll probably find a lot of information, like [this one](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: Best not to send raw bit, rather a serialised message created by you.  There are also libraries that do this eg [Protocol Buffers from Google](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)

Comment: This networking programming guide on Network Byte Order might be useful: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#byte-order

Comment: The short answer is: "Don't do that." Define a format for the data on the wire. The server needs to convert its data to that format, and the client needs to parse that format. Most other methods are short trips into madness.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys. It seems then that ```char```s are guaranteed to have a specific bit representation?